# Sorting of NSDictionary by amount of children per key

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, nsdictionary, nssortdescriptor

After searching the developer docs, google and other sites I still can't find how to accomplish the following...

I would like to sort a NSDictionary by the amount of values (i.e. count) per key. Do I need to use a custom NSSortDescriptor and if so, I would really appreciate some help with the code. Below is an example of the NSDictionary I would like sorted.

2 ways I would like to be able to sort dictionary:

1) Sort it so that the key "Australia" comes first because it has 3 cities, then USA with 2 cities, and finally UK with 1 city?

2) For a bonus I would also love to have the option to sort by the amount of objects i.e. Australia first with 6 objects, then UK with 4 objects (even though only 1 city) then USA with 2 objects.

```
"United Kingdom" = {
    "City 1" = {
        1 = "Object A";
        2 = "Object B";
        3 = "Object C";
        4 = "Object D";
    };
};
"Australia" = {
    "City 1" = {
        5 = "Object E";
        6 = "Object F";
        7 = "Object G";
    };
    "City 2" = {
        8 = "Object H";
        9 = "Object I";
    };
    "City 3" = {
        10 = "Object J";
    };
};
"United States of America" = {
    "City 1" = {
        11 = "Object K";
    };
    "City 2" = {
        12 = "Object L";
    };
};
```

Comment: NSDictionary has only one value per key. Do you mean you store NSArrays in an NSDictionary and want to sort it by the number of elements in each NSArray?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you do store arrays in the dictionary you could do something like this:

```
NSComparator sorter = ^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b)
{
    NSArray* a1 = a;
    NSArray* a2 = b;
    if([a1 count] > [a2 count]) return NSOrderedAscending; 
    if([a1 count] < [a2 count]) return NSOrderedDescending; 
    return NSOrderedSame;
}

NSArray* ordered = [dictionary keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:sorter];
```

Then in the "ordered" array you'll get the keys to the dictionary in the order of increasing number of elements in the arrays stored in the dictionary.

Comment: SVD, Thanks so much! I knew I had to be converting the dictionary into arrays at some point to do the sorting but thought I would just include the problem and the raw data set I had. This is exactly what I am looking for to be able to accomplish the first part of the question. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

A NSDictionary is a Key—Value collection. It is not sortable. You will have to convert it to a NSArray (of NSArrays) instead.

For NSArray you will find several ways to do sorting:

- with [SortDescriptors](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCJGCJI)
- with [Comparator-Blocks](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-SW28)
- with [selector](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BABBHAGJ) (methods)
- with [(C)-Functions](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000137-BBCHBAHB)